# How to parse one digit at time from a decimal number?

Tags: c, parsing, ascii

How do I convert a letter that holds two digits into decimal, then only parse 1 digit at a time? For example ...

```
char letter = 'D';
char firstDigit, secondDigit;
```

'D' is 68 in decimal, now this how I want to divide the decimal number amond my two varibles.

```
firstDigit = 6

secondDigit = 8
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: at least in ascii every letter char  code is two digit.

Comment: witch `6` or  `'6'` ?

Comment: 'C' in ascii = 68 so i just want to parse the 6 and 8 and store them into variables separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us call your ASCII strings encoding a number a *packed* string. We define a function `packed_get` reading the `k`-th digit contained by such a packed string:

```
/* packed_get(S, K)
    Return the K-th digit of S. */
char
packed_get(char *s, int k)
{
  int a = -1;
  if(k % 2)
  {
    a = s[k/2] % 10;
  }
  else
  {
    a = s[k/2] / 10;
  }
  return '0' + a;
}
```

The `return` statement assumes `ASCII` encoding and return the digit as the character representing the digit not as the digit itself. You can easily change this if returning the digit as a number is more appropriate. The second function that we need to iterate over *packed strings* is a function coputing the length, that is, the number of digits we can read from such a string:

```
/* packed_length(S)
    Return the length of S. */
int
packed_length(char *s)
{
  return 2*strlen(s);
}
```

The following program illustrates the use of these two functions. It unpacks `DEMONSTRATION` into `68697779788384826584737978`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* packed_length(S)
    Return the length of S. */
int
packed_length(char *s)
{
  return 2*strlen(s);
}

/* packed_get(S, K)
    Return the K-th digit of S. */
char
packed_get(char *s, int k)
{
  int a = -1;
  if(k % 2)
  {
    a = s[k/2] % 10;
  }
  else
  {
    a = s[k/2] / 10;
  }
  return '0' + a;
}

int
main()
{
  char* demo = "DEMONSTRATION";
  for(int i = 0; i < packed_length(demo); ++i)
  {
    putchar(packed_get(demo, i));
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int firstDigit = ((int)letter)/10;
int secondDigit = ((int)letter)%10;
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: It works without, but I'm accustomed to the compiler complaining if I don't.

Answer (score -2):

If this is Java:

```
char letter = 'D';

int intLetter = (int) letter;
char[] digits = Integer.toString(intLetter).toCharArray();
```

Now you have the two digits in the digits array you can transform back to ints:

```
digits[0] = 6
digits[1] = 8
```

Then you can perform any operation with those.

You can even do it in one line like:

```
char[] digits = Integer.toString((int) letter).toCharArray();
```